# Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupLongTermRetentionPolicies

Tags: sql-server, backup

I am trying to add long term retention policy on the SQL DB using azure policy with Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupLongTermRetentionPolicies. Seems like there is an issue with my current policy which I am not able to find it. Can you help me with this please

```
{

  "properties": {

      "displayName": "DINE-SQLDBBackup",

      "policyType": "Custom",

      "mode": "Indexed",

      "description": "This policy checks Azure SQL Databases enabled for long term backup retention period. ",

      "metadata": {

          "version": "1.1.0",

          "category": "SQL",

          "createdBy": "5623789b-3072-41a7-8b9b-74d388241482",

          "createdOn": "2021-05-19T11: 57: 08.9261396Z",

          "updatedBy": null,

          "updatedOn": null

      },

      "parameters": {

          "effect": {

              "type": "String",

              "metadata": {

                  "displayName": "Effect",

                  "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the policy."

              },

              "allowedValues": [

                  "DeployIfNotExists",

                  "Disabled"

              ],

              "defaultValue": "DeployIfNotExists"

          }

      },

      "policyRule": {

          "if": {

              "field": "type",

              "equals": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases"

          },

          "then": {

              "effect": "[parameters('effect')]",

              "details": {

                  "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupLongTermRetentionPolicies/write",

                  "name": "default",

                  "roleDefinitionIds": [

                      "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/9b7fa17d-e63e-47b0-bb0a-15c516ac86ec"

                  ],

                  "existenceCondition": {

                      "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupLongTermRetentionPolicies/retentionDays",

                      "equals": "[parameters('retentionDays')]"

                  },

                  "deployment": {

                      "properties": {

                          "mode": "incremental",

                          "template": {

                              "$schema": "https: //schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",

                              "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",

                              "parameters": {

                                  "serverName": {

                                      "type": "string"

                                  }

                              },

                              "resources": [

                                  {

                                      "name": "[concat(parameters('serverName'),'/default')]",

                                      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupLongTermRetentionPolicies/write",

                                      "apiVersion": "2017-10-01-preview",

                                      "properties": {

                                          "weeklyRetention": "PT5S",

                                          "monthlyRetention": "PT0S",

                                          "yearlyRetention": "PT1S",

                                          "weekOfYear": 0

                                      }

                                  }

                              ]

                          },

                          "parameters": {

                              "serverName": {

                                  "value": "[field('fullname')]"

                              }

                          }

                      }

                  }

              }

          }

      }

  },

  "id": "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/DINE-SQLDBBackup",

  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",

  "name": "DINE-SQLDBBackup"

}
```

made some changes on the policy but still not seen any compliant

Comment: I'm "glad" to see you removed some of your personal data this time. As someone who works for the housing association who owns the building I live in, however, I'm a little concerned for the responsibility you take on ensuring you remove that data *before* sharing it on the internet.